# How to save/load scene models with the Quest 3

Tags: unity-game-engine, unreal-engine5, oculusquest

Does anyone have an idea on how to store and load scene models (room setup for quest 3) at runtime?

It feels like an important feature to be missing from the SDK.

In the end I want to make it that once a player leaves the current room the next room is loaded in and populated (without the need for rescanning)